# PHP bot assigning upload path

Tags: php, html, css, file

I'm having an issue where the path of my file upload isn't being assigned to the correct folder. It actually amends the file path to the file name of the file being uploaded. Weird right? Here's the code I'm working on...

```
<?php
      $allowed_filetypes = array('.mp4','.gif','.bmp','.png','.html','.psd','.zip','.xml','.css','.js',);
      $max_filesize = 5904288;
      $upload_path = 'video';

   $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
   $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

   if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
      die('Sorry, cannot take files over blankKB.');

   if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('Sorry, cannot take files over blankKB.');

   if(!is_writable($upload_path))
     die('We are very sorry, a problem is occurring with the CHMOD  of this directory');

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $filename))
         echo ' Your file was uploaded successfully, view it <a href="file.php?file=' . $filename . '" target="_blank" title="Your File">here</a>';
      else
         echo 'Sorry, but there was an error during the file upload. Please try again.';
?>
```

Here's what the file looks like after being uploaded,

> videoHello.png

plus it doesn't upload the file to the directory I want it in, located at /video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `$upload_path . $filename` you are only concatenating the two strings, which does indeed result in `videoHello.png`;

You should either concatenate your system's directory separator (On Unix based systems it's `/`)

```
$upload_path . '/' . $filename
```

or build the separator into your string `$upload_path`

```
$upload_path = 'video/';
```

Though my final advice would be to use Absolute Paths like this:

```
$upload_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/video/';
```

Comment: Technically you should be using `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. Otherwise, +1. :)

Comment: Ah, I would have never thought of that. Thank you, it worked :)